# Horizontal Scroll View iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uibutton

I wanted to ask if it is possible to use the UIScrollView horizontally. I have an app that plays different radio stations, each station is represented by an UIButton. How can i place i.e 3 buttons in a row so when i scroll another three UIButtons appear?

Below you can find how the design is supposed to look like.

Thank you very much!

[image]

Comment: Please read UIScrollView documentation. You will see it is possible to scroll horizontally as well as vertically.https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html

Comment: @DarshanKunjadiya I can't see any answer from you posted here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It works exactly the same as vertically. Just set the `scrollview.contentSize.width` greater than `scrollview.frame.size.width`.